# Mount a HDD CentOS 6

Tags: hard-drive, centos

I'm trying to mount a drive connected to my dedicated server. It is running off a SSD boot drive and I want to mount and be able to access my HDD.

```
[root@server1mc /]# mount /dev/sdb1 /hdd1
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Update as requested:

```
[root@server1mc /]# pvdisplay -m /dev/sdb1
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 12.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29808
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29808
  PV UUID               JYMqm7-cwGc-7r9Y-9myF-xOEa-4jTa-Jm3iOd

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 29679:
    Logical volume      /dev/vg/lv_root
    Logical extents     0 to 29679
  Physical extent 29680 to 29807:
    Logical volume      /dev/vg/lv_swap
    Logical extents     0 to 127


[root@server1mc ~]# mount /dev/vg/lv_root /vg-lv_root
mount: mount point /vg-lv_root does not exist
```

Comment: What do `file -s /dev/sdb1` and `pvdisplay /dev/sdb1` say?

Comment: 1st shows: [root@server1mc /]# file -s /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: JYMqm7cwGc7r9Y9myFxOEa4jTaJm3iO

Comment: 2nd shows:[root@server1mc /]# pvdisplay /dev/sdb1
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 12.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29808
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29808
  PV UUID               JYMqm7-cwGc-7r9Y-9myF-xOEa-4jTa-Jm3iOd

Answer (score 2):

As `file` and `pvdisplay` have shown, that partition is a a Physical Volume (PV) which is part of the Volume Group (VG) named **vg**. To see what Logical Volumes (LVs) that PV contains, run:

```
pvdisplay -m /dev/sdb1
```

To activate the VG you need to run

```
vgchange -a y vg
```

Then you should be able to mount its LVs if they are located *only* on that PV (i.e. they're not split between this PV and other PVs located on unavailable disks). You have a LV named **lv_root** on it, so in order to use it run:

```
mkdir /mnt/vg-lv_root # if it doesn't exist already
mount /dev/vg/lv_root /mnt/vg-lv_root
```

You also have a LV named **lv_swap**, but that's probably just a swap partition. Run `file -s /dev/vg/lv_swap` to confirm.

When you're done, you need to do the opposite. First `umount` the LVs, for example:

```
umount /dev/vg/lv_root
```

Then deactivate the VG if you're planning to remove the disk while the computer is running (like in the case of an external drive):

```
vgchange -a n vg
```

Comment: Added to top of thread.

Comment: @MitchMays: I've updated the answer for your setup.

Comment: It came up with (at top of thread).

Comment: @MitchMays: you need to make sure that the directory where you're mounting exists. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: LV root is the SSD (main, boot drive), we're trying to mount a secondary 1 TB Hard drive.

Comment: `pvdisplay` says otherwise. Are you sure that the secondary drive is **sdb**? Also why wouldn't it have a LV named **lv_root** on it?

Comment: fwiw, this answer also works for centos 7.

Comment: And in fact, something seems to have automagically figured out it was a LV and made the partitions available in /dev/dm-2 and /dev/dm-3  after I ran `ls -1 /sys/class/scsi_host/*/scan | xargs -I scan sudo sh -c "echo '- - -' > scan"` (I hot plugged a .vmdk file into my vm, which is why I was triggering the scsi scans)

Answer (score 0):

an LVM is Logical Volume Management.  It means that this disk belongs to an existing LVM and will not be useable outside the LVM group.

Comment: Can you help in more detail, I just need the command to mount it.